# How to use groupBy on object in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, group-by

I have an object as below:

```
obj = {
 'fruita' : 'eat',
 'fruitb' : 'eat',
 'fruitc' : 'throw',
 'fruitd' : 'throw'
}

output = {
 'eat' : ['fruita','fruitb'],
 'throw' : ['fruitc','fruitd']
}
```

How to apply _.groupBy in order to get the list of eat and throw fruits seperately?

Answer (score 0):

We can turn our object to an array of key-value pairs:

```
var keyValues = Object.keys(obj).map(key => ({ key, value: obj[key] }));
```

And then we can perform a `reduce` to construct our object:

```
var values = keyValues.reduce((acc, kv) => {
    if (typeof acc[kv.value] === 'undefined') {
        acc[kv.value] = [];
    }

    acc[kv.value].push(kv.key);
    return acc;
}, {});
```

No lodash necessary!

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `for..in` loop to set properties of `output` object to values of `obj` , push `obj` properties to items within array at `output`

```js
var obj = {
 'fruita' : 'eat',
 'fruitb' : 'eat',
 'fruitc' : 'throw',
 'fruitd' : 'throw'
}

var output = {};

for (var prop in obj) {
  if (!output[obj[prop]]) {
    output[obj[prop]] = [];
    output[obj[prop]].push(prop)
  } else {
    output[obj[prop]].push(prop)
  }
}

console.log(output)
```